# Convert string into reseved word in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

[image]

I have this drop-down(how_often). If a user select 2 weeks then i want to send an email using delayed jobs like this:

```
mymailer.delay(:run_at => how_often.from_now).send_email
```

here I get "2.weeks" in how_often which is a string and the above code doesn't work as we can do as:

```
mymailer.delay(:run_at => 2.weeks.from_now).send_email
```

How to convert how_often(string) into reserved words like: 2.weeks, 2.months etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could probably do it with eval:

mymailer.delay(:run_at => eval(how_often).from_now).send_email

Comment: wanna click the answered button?

Comment: Yes,I wanna click the answered button.

Comment: Did the eval answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this eval is the answer.